# Bidirectional Binding of mutually dependent Properties in QML

Tags: qt, qml

While learning QML I stumbled over the problem, that I have to properties that are mutually dependent.

E.g. the user may set a value with a slider, or enter it with a textinput.
While moving the slider, the text in the textinput should be updated while when entering a value in the textinput, the sliders position needs to  be adjusted.

Now I have the two properties: the x-value of the slider, and the text in the textinput. I need to convert them into the same format (for example: percent), and update them vice versa.
Setting up two bindings would result in a binding loop, which is probably not a good thing to have.

I think, this is a very common problem, so I am sure there is some "gold standard" to solve it. However I can't find a suitable solution.

The only way that comes to my mind, is not to use bindings at all, but handling the signals, that one of the values has changed manually (if I can't overwrite the setter in C++).
Is that all you can do?

Good day to you!
-m-

EDIT:
I now tried it with conditionally binding the value of the slider to the percentage value.

The object `handle` is the marker on the slider, `handleArea` is the MouseArea attached to it, that allows the dragging.

```
Binding {
    target: root
    property: 'percent'
    value: handle.x / handleBar.width
    when: handleArea.drag.active
}

Binding {
    target: handle
    property: 'x'
    value: root.percent * handleBar.width
    when: !handleArea.drag.active
}
```

It works. But is it a good style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make one property that will store the mutual value. When user inputs text or moves slider they will use a function to update the mutual value. They will also listen to the value change and adjust their value to it.

Here is working example

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 80
    title: "Mutual value test"

    property double mutualValue: 0
    function setMutualValue(value)
    {
        if (typeof(value) === "string")
        {
            value = value.replace(",", ".");
            value = parseFloat(value)
        }
        mutualValue = value
    }

    TextInput {
        width: 200
        height: 40
        validator: DoubleValidator {}
        onEditingFinished:
        {
            focus = false
            setMutualValue(text)
        }
        onFocusChanged:
        {
            if (text === inputHelp && focus)
                text = ""
        }
        property alias mutualValue: window.mutualValue
        onMutualValueChanged: setValue(mutualValue)
        property string inputHelp
        color: (text === inputHelp && !focus ? "grey" : "black")
        function setValue(mutualValue)
        {
            inputHelp = mutualValue.toFixed(3)
            text = inputHelp
        }
    }

    Slider {
        x: 200
        width: 200
        height: 40
        onValueChanged: setMutualValue(value)
        property alias mutualValue: window.mutualValue
        onMutualValueChanged: setValue(mutualValue)
        function setValue(mutualValue)
        {
            value = mutualValue
        }
    }

    Text {
        x: (parent.width - width) / 2
        y: 40 + (40 - height) / 2
        text: "Current value is: " + (window.mutualValue * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
    }
}
```